# Test the following series is convergence $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-n+(-1)^n}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Test the following series is convergence $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-n+(-1)^n}$

By Ratio test $$ L=\bigg{|}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\bigg{|}=\bigg{|} \frac{2^{-(n+1)+(-1)^{n+1}}}{2^{-n+(-1)^n}}\bigg{|}=2^{-1+2(-1)^{n+1}}$$

This follows $L$ is either ${2}$ or $2^{-3}$,But this series is converge when I used Root test.

Why doesn't ratio test work?

Comment: The ratio test sometimes doesn't converge. In some cases that it doesn't converge it can still give you the answer. For example, if the $\liminf$ were $>1$ it would tell you that it diverges. If the $\limsup$ there $<1$ it would tell you that it converges. This example shows that it could happen that none of those are satisfied.

Comment: The ratio test is inconclusive. There is nothing wrong with it, it is just not strong enough to provide a result in this case.

Comment: @plop Thank you very much

Comment: @Kolja  Thank you very much

Comment: @311411 What do you mean by L  is either one or minus one?

Comment: The terms have a constant factor oscillation from one term to the next. A small variation of the ratio test like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Ali's_second_ratio_test) can avoid that problem.

Comment: @plop I think it would be nice if you combined your comments into an answer

Comment: Sorry DARK, please ignore my previous comment. Your calculation is right. This is a good example to remember. It converges but $\limsup|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|>1.$

Comment: Root test gives immediate answer and, imho, is more appropriate.

Comment: An alternative to the root test is rearrangement. The sum is $3$, since we have a rearrangement of the absolutely convergent $2+2^{-1}+2^{-2}+2^{-3}+\dots$

Comment: The root test gives $\sqrt[n]{2^{-n+(-1)^n}}=2^{-1+\tfrac{(-1)^n}{n}}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2}<1$ when you can conclude that the series converges.